# Creating an application with no dock icon for Mac (C# / Mono)

Tags: c#, macos, mono, background, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System Tray only (no dock icon) application using C# / Mono on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414629/system-tray-only-no-dock-icon-application-using-c-mono-on-mac)

I'm curious if there is any method through which I may create and run a Mac application using Mono / C# that doesn't display itself in the dock?

I'm hoping to only display my icon in the system tray, similar to how Dropbox, LogMeIn, and other "background" type applications work.

Is this possible with C# / Mono on a Mac? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of your own questions.  This is almost identical to your question [System Tray only (no dock icon) application using C# / Mono on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414629/system-tray-only-no-dock-icon-application-using-c-mono-on-mac), which you posted two days earlier.

Comment: Dear moderators, you should close the question that has no answers instead of the one that does. Or merge them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OS X doesn't have a "system tray" (aka "notification area" in MS Windows).

Are you talking about a "menu extra" -- the icons that live on the right side of the OS X menu bar?

Or something else?

The short answer is maybe not. See [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921996/building-a-menu-extra-that-implements-all-the-features-seen-in-system-menu-extras):

Answer (score 0):

since, and in order to run any mono developed software in a mac you have to go through the mono app the only realistic solution is to modify and recompile the source code of the mono.app to your needs.

http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono